# How can I draw random samples from a skewed normal distribution in Python?

Tags: python, random, skew

I have this skewed normal distribution:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
def skewnorm(xi,w,a,x):

    m = (x-xi)/w 

    return (2/((w)))*norm.pdf(m)*norm.cdf(a*m)
```

I would like to generate random samples with this distribution with certain values for xi,w and a in order to implement a montecarlo simulation with some stocks returns.

I would like to do the same as: `np.random.normal(mean, std, n)`but with my skewed normal distribution.

Can you help me?
thank you very much

Comment: does the `scipy.stats.skewnorm()` not do what you want

Comment: `r = skewnorm.rvs(a, size=1000)` from stats would generate required RV